# pthread setup for apache2

Tags: php, pthreads, php-7.2

I am using Ubuntu 14.10 (c9.io) and upgraded my php to 7.2 from 5.6.

I need to use pthread for multi threading for apache2. I am trying to install pthread using sudo pecl install pthreads

But this gives me following error:

```
checking whether to enable pthreads... yes, shared
checking whether to enable AddressSanitizer for pthreads... no
checking whether to enable dmalloc for pthreads... no
checking for ZTS... configure: error: pthreads requires ZTS, please re-compile PHP with ZTS enabled
ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/pthreads/configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config' failed
```

I tried to find some solution for this but no success. Every solution is installing the PHP from scratch rather than re-compiling the existing PHP setup.

Please suggest if there is any way we can use pthread for apache2 php 7.2 setup.

Comment: Just a suggestion: Avoid using PECL and stick to packages specifically tailored to your OS. That said, there is the pthreads PHP module and there is the pthreads library (which stands for POSIX threads) that is a C library. Those two can easily be confused, because PHP is written in C.

Answer (score -2):

As an example taking `PHP 7.0` and review the steps. From checking your errors, you might require `ZTS`

**1. Install ZTS enabled PHP**

pThreads won’t install without the `php7.0-zts-xml` and `php7.0-zts-dev` packages, so these must also be installed:

```
sudo apt -y install php7.0-zts php7.0-zts-common php7.0-zts-xml php7.0-zts-dev
```

**2. Check ZTS is enabled**

This should return an integer of `1`.

```
php -r "echo PHP_ZTS;"
```

**3.  Install pThreads via Pecl**

```
sudo apt install php-pear
sudo pecl install pthreads
sudo echo "extension=pthreads.so" >> /etc/php/7.0-zts/mods-available/pthreads.ini
sudo echo "extension=pthreads.so" >> /etc/php/7.0-zts/cli/conf.d/pthreads.ini
```

**4. Check pThreads is installed**

This should return an integer of ‘1’.

```
php -r "print_r(class_exists('Thread'));"
```

[For more reference](https://www.rapidspike.com/blog/php7-pthreads/)

Comment: I tried this - sudo apt -y install php7.2-zts php7.2-zts-common php7.2-zts-xml php7.2-zts-dev but I believe there are no such packages available.


E: Unable to locate package php7.2-zts
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.2-zts'
E: Unable to locate package php7.2-zts-common
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.2-zts-common'
E: Unable to locate package php7.2-zts-xml
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.2-zts-xml'
E: Unable to locate package php7.2-zts-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.2-zts-dev'

Comment: I am also getting same error as @XyrinTechnologies mentioned.

Comment: Literally not a single one of those packages in step 1 exists